# Identity function on a smooth world

Tags: analysis, continuity, infinity, infinitesimals

For anyone who is familiar with the concept of smooth world (from Bell), is the identity function $f(x)=x$ continuous in that world? Cheers!

Comment: Have you [read this Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_infinitesimal_analysis)? Assuming you mean $f = id_\mathbb{R}$, then it says the answer is yes, according to a basic theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the identity function is continuous.  That's because if $\Delta x$ is infinitesimal, then also $\Delta x$ is always infinitesimal.